# Can accessibility options be toggles programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility

Is there a method by which specific accessibility options can be enabled? I am hoping that, similar to the request for user location access, users can be prompted to enable accessibility options. The mono audio and speaker balance toggles are two good examples.